# Difference between SAP and NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, sap

SAP and NetSuite are top leading Enterprise Resource Planning(ERP) platforms.
SAP SE is a German multinational software and NetSuite is owned by Oracle.
But I'm not sure which one is better.
Please let me know if someone has rich knowledge about both of them.

---

Comment: Stack Overflow is about programming questions. SAP (SAP SE) and NetSuite are software *COMPANIES*, they are not platforms, they are not software. SAP company has hundreds of software, of platforms, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetSuite: It primarily targets small and medium-sized businesses (SMBs) but also serves larger enterprises. It offers a wide range of industry-specific solutions.

SAP: SAP caters to businesses of all sizes, including SMBs and large enterprises. It has a strong presence in industries such as manufacturing, finance, and logistics.

So, NetSuite is a cloud-based ERP system primarily targeting SMBs, offering customization and flexibility, faster implementation time, and a subscription-based pricing model, while SAP caters to businesses of all sizes, provides extensive customization options, and offers both on-premises and cloud-based solutions with a more complex implementation process and pricing structure.